# Why does my mesh have lots of square on it?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I made a render animation but the mesh seems to be too bright and it seems too square if you understand. Well, I'll add a screenshot, and I want to know what can I do to make it look better.

[image]

Comment: I also heard it might be the light or the background but any opinion would help

Comment: For the "squares," try shade smooth (in the left panel, right above the "Data").  I think there is a modifier called "Edge Split" that does something similar, but leaves sharp edges alone.  You didn't say what look you are going for, so I can't really comment on it being too bright or dark.

Comment: Well I want it to look more curvy you know?, thanks a lot for the opinion

Comment: The smooth shading helped a lot thats what I needed. Thanks a lot Gliderman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select the mesh. Then click on the *Tools* Tab, and under *Shading* click *Smooth*.  Another option would be to subdivide the mesh.

Edit:
Also, if you don't want the bright spots, go to *Properties* > *Material* and change the *Specular Intensity* to zero.